# Design : multiple visits per patient

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

[image]

Above is my schema.  What you can't see in tblPatientVisits is the foreign key from `tblPatient`, which is `patientid`.

`tblPatient` contains a distinct copies of each patient in the dataset as well as their gender.  `tblPatientVists` contains their demographic information, where they lived at time of admission and which hospital they went to.  I chose to put that information into a separate table because it changes throughout the data (a person can move from one visit to the next and go to a different hospital).

I don't get any strange numbers with my queries until I add tblPatientVisits.  There are just under one millions claims in `tblClaims`, but when I add `tblPatientVisits` so I can check out where that person was from, it returns over million.  I thinkthis is due to the fact that in `tblPatientVisits` the same patientID shows up more than once (due to the fact that they had different admission/dischargedates).

For the life of me I can't see where this is incorrect design, nor do I know how to rectify it beyond doing one query with `count(tblPatientVisits.PatientID=1` and then `union` with `count(tblPatientVisits.patientid)>1`.

Any insight into this type of design, or how I might more elegantly find a way to get the claimType from `tblClaims` to give me the correct number of rows with I associate a claim ID with a patientID?

EDIT: The biggest problem I'm having is the fact that if I include the `admissionDate,dischargeDate` or the `patientState`in the tblPatient table I can't use the patientID as a primary key.

It should be noted that `tblClaims` are `NOT` necessarily related to `tblPatientVisits.admissionDate, tblPatientVisits.dischargeDate`.

EDIT:  sample queries to show that when tblPatientVisits is added, more rows are returned than claims

```
SELECT     tblclaims.id, tblClaims.claimType
FROM         tblClaims INNER JOIN
                      tblPatientClaims ON tblClaims.id = tblPatientClaims.id INNER JOIN
                      tblPatient ON tblPatientClaims.patientid = tblPatient.patientID INNER JOIN
                      tblPatientVisits ON tblPatient.patientID = tblPatientVisits.patientID
```

more than one million query rows returned

```
SELECT     tblClaims.id, tblPatient.patientID
FROM         tblClaims INNER JOIN
                      tblPatientClaims ON tblClaims.id = tblPatientClaims.id INNER JOIN
                      tblPatient ON tblPatientClaims.patientid = tblPatient.patientID
```

less than one million query rows returned

[image: sample rows]

[image: more than one million rows]

Comment: If a patient has multiple claims, how do you expect to associate just one claim ID with that patient? (Which seems to be what you're after - since a patient can have different claims and different claim types, and this is probably the problem with joining multiple visits per patient with multiple claims per patient.) Can you somehow associate each visit with a specific claim?

Comment: You want to join the claims with the visits. you don't have a direct way to do it, you should at least add the date of the claim with the date of the visit

Comment: You keep the same patientID in the junction table and the tblclaims.id changes.  so claim 1, 2, and 3 could be all for patient 123

Comment: @Lamak since the same person keeps the same ID throughout the dataset, adding their admission dates and discharge dates would cause a repeat of the patientID.  That's why that information is in the tblPatientVisits table.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results. I'm about done with trying to solve word problems. We don't need a ton of data, but 5 or 10 source rows including a few rows that result in "duplicates" with your current query should do it. Also, if you are trying to associate visits with claims, why isn't there a claimID on the visits table? Otherwise what is the point of the join?

Comment: In other words, if a patient has three claims, and four visits, how on earth in your model do you know which visit is associated with which claim? It seems like both ClaimID and PatientID should belong in tblPatientVisits.

Comment: Also note, your current model allows for a many-to-many relationship between patients and claims.  In other words, a claim could belong to multiple patients.  Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: No, that is not correct.  But one patient can have multiple claims.  the trick thing is only one of the claims in tblClaims is related to a record in tblPatientVisits - and it's impossible for me to guess which one.  It does seem to make sense now that I've taken a step back to look at it that claimID should be in the `tblPatient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is crying for a better design. I really think that a visit should be associated with a claim, and that a claim can only be associated with a single patient, so I think the design should be (and eliminating the needless `tbl` prefix, which is just clutter):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Patients
(
  PatientID INT PRIMARY KEY
  -- , ... other columns ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Claims
(
  ClaimID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  PatientID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
    REFERENCES dbo.Patients(PatientID)
  -- , ... other columns ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.PatientVisits
(
  PatientID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
    REFERENCES dbo.Patients(PatientID),
  ClaimID INT NULL FOREIGN KEY 
    REFERENCES dbo.Claims(ClaimID),
  VisitDate DATE
  , -- ... other columns ...
  , PRIMARY KEY (PatientID, ClaimID, VisitDate) -- not convinced on this one
);
```

There is some redundant information here, but it's not clear from your model whether a patient can have a visit that is *not* associated with a specific claim, or even whether you know that a visit belongs to a specific claim (this seems like crucial information given the type of query you're after).

In any case, given your current model, one query you might try is:

```
SELECT c.id, c.claimType
FROM dbo.tblClaims AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.tblPatientClaims AS pc
ON c.id = pc.id
INNER JOIN dbo.tblPatient AS p
ON pc.patientid = p.patientID
-- where exists tells SQL server you don't care how many 
-- visits took place, as long as there was at least one:
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tblPatientVisits AS pv
  WHERE pv.patientID = p.patientID);
```

This will still return one row for every patient / claim combination, but it should only return one row per patient / visit combination. Again, it really feels like the design isn't right here. You should also get in the habit of using table aliases - they make your query much easier to read, especially if you insist on the messy `tbl` prefix. You should also always use the `dbo` (or whatever schema you use) prefix when creating and referencing objects.

Comment: I think what I'm trying to do might be impossible with the current schema.  There is at least `one` claim associated with a person, but because people aren't billed when they are discharged, it's impossible to tell which claim it is exactly - just they this person has X number of claims and X number of visits.  I'll take care to be more thorough when asking questions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the concept of a claim but I suspect you want to remove the link table between claims and patient and instead make the association between patient visit and a claim.

Would that work out better for you?

Comment: Actually the more I think about it, are you happy with demographic information being stored in the visits table? Surely most people don't move about that often?

Comment: I think that's demographic information about the visit, not their residence. I can get medical treatment when I'm traveling to North Carolina even if I live in Rhode Island.

Comment: They don't.  I suppose that information could be in the `tblClaims`, but that didn't seem right to me since their residence doesn't affect their claim

Comment: Either way an address table maybe useful, with patient id and residence to and from dates